# Setting up SBT with SVN integration

Tags: eclipse, svn, sbt

I work for a small company of software consultants, that does development primarily (currently: solely) for the JVM using Eclipse as our IDE of choice.

Until now, we have not been using any Project Management/Build Tools. We have used a company SVN repository for version control of our projects along with any binary dependencies (well JAR dependencies) of same. This has gotten a bit messy, and we have a lot of extraneous *.jar files in lib folders across our projects.

With our recent shift to Scala as our PL of choice, we have also looked into using SBT as build tool. We have set up a Sonatype Nexus repository, and have begun declaring SBT files for our projects

The thing is, that we have a set of utility projects that are used across a lot of projects for our customers. Until now, we have managed inter-project dependencies by having an Eclipse workspace for each customer project, with each of these having a local version of the utility projects on which it has dependencies. Keeping local versions up to date has therefore been handled solely through SVN commits and updates.

I guess that there are a couple of different ways that we could go about structuring our projects and workspaces. Using SBT to define inter-project dependencies, it would make sense to have a workspace for the utility projects alone, and then importing snapshots/releases as managed dependencies in our customer projects. However, since we often make enhancements to the utility projects during development of the customer projects, it would be nice to still be able to do this in the same workspace and as much on the fly as possible.

From: http://www.devdaily.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse it seems that a plugin exists for Git that grabs current versions from a Git repository, builds the source and includes them in the Eclipse classpath. This sort of setup would allow us to continue to use the revision control system as the main means of distributing project updates, though I have not been able to find something similar for SVN...

**Is anyone using SBT with SVN and eclipse, and/or knows of a smart way to setup interproject dependencies without firing a lot of publish/publish-locals alongside the SVN commands?**

*It would be nice to somehow declare interproject dependencies using SBT, since this would allow us to dump the responsibility for transient managed dependencies on SBT...*

Comment: I have a continuous integration setup with Jenkins triggered by a hook from my github repository when someone pushes code. Then Jenkins publishes the newest build to a private maven repository.

All dependencies across projects are downloaded from that remote repository and not from local builds. That way everyone uses the newest builds and if they want to work on it they only have to worry about sending commits.

Comment: @ThomasLazaro I have thought about setting up Jenkins, though not in this context (however, I can see how it would solve this problem)... If we were to setup Jenkins, we would probably want to take advantage of Jenkins as a full CI setup... Do you have any idea of how Jenkins integrate with SBT? Also, do you know anything about the toolset for running testsuites with one of the test frameworks for Scala and having Jenkins perform static analysis on Scala code?